# How to display image in show ModalPopupExtender

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview where i am having a link button. I am showing a popup using ModalPopupExtender and there should be image in ModalPopupExtender. This image source is dynamic means on clicking each link button , different image should be display.

```
<div>

                <asp:Panel ID="collapsiblePanelBody" runat="server"  
                    ScrollBars="Auto" >
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewProf"  runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowPaging="True" CssClass="clGrid" PageSize="25" 
                        onpageindexchanging="GridViewProf_PageIndexChanging" 
                        EnableModelValidation="True" onrowcommand="GridViewProf_RowCommand" 
                        onrowdatabound="GridViewProf_RowDataBound" 
                        onpageindexchanged="GridViewProf_PageIndexChanged"  >


                         <Columns>    

 <asp:BoundField DataField="Document_Conventional" HeaderText="Document_Conventional" >
                    <HeaderStyle Width="50%" CssClass="gridHeader"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="gridItem" HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>

 <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Show Image" >
                  <ItemTemplate>
     <input id="lnkImg" runat="server" type="button" value="ShowImage" />
     <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkImg" PopupControlID="Panel1">
     </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>


<asp:Panel ID="Panel1"   
    style="border:solid 2px #cccccc;" runat="server" 
    Width="60%" Height="60%" >
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" style="border:solid 2px #cccccc; width:98%; cursor: move;">Drag Panel
</asp:Panel>


 <img  id="img05"  width="400" height="320" runat="server"
               alt="image"  />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="[ X ]" />


        </asp:Panel>
```

// Thats what i have done. But how to give src to image dynamically , i am not able to do. Please help me out

Comment: you can use link button click event, within that event you can pass your image path dynamically :)

Comment: can u please give an example

Comment: Use Handler to show Images dynamically

Comment: why do you want to show an image in Modelpopup extender?Are you going to show only an image or what?

Comment: I want to show Only image.

Comment: where you having an image Path ?

Comment: At Application level

Answer (score 0):

What I typically do is a create a very lightweight HTTPHandler to serve the images:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace Example
{  
    public class GetImage : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.QueryString("id") != null)
            {
                Blob = GetBlobFromDataBase(id);
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/pjpeg";
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(Blob);
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can reference this directly in your img tag:

```
<img src="GetImage.ashx?id=111"/>
```

Or, you could even create a server control that does it for you:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Example.WebControl
{

    [ToolboxData("<{0}:DatabaseImage runat=server></{0}:DatabaseImage>")]
    public class DatabaseImage : Control
    {

        public int DatabaseId
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["DatabaseId" + this.ID] == null)
                    return 0;
                else
                    return ViewState["DataBaseId"];
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["DatabaseId" + this.ID] = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write("<img src='getImage.ashx?id=" + this.DatabaseId + "'/>");
            base.RenderContents(output);
        }
    }
}
```

This could be used like

```
<cc:DatabaseImage id="db1" DatabaseId="123" runat="server/>
```

Comment: <img src="GetImage.ashx?id=<%# Eval("Image_ID")%>"/> You can pass Image Id dynamically like this

Answer (score 0):

eg:

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow grid = (GridViewRow)lnk.NamingContainer;

        LinkButton linkbtn = (LinkButton)grid.FindControl("LinkButton1"); //get your Id here
        string id=linkbtn .Text;
        Image img = (Image)grid.FindControl("Image1");

        string path="~/Images/addnew.jpg";
        img.ImageUrl = path;
    }
```

if you have path in your Database get the path by the Id of the linkbutton

Comment: I am not having LinkButton

Comment: you said  that "This image source is dynamic means on clicking each link button"

Comment: King_Fisher just wanted to ask, is it really possible to call LinkButton1_Click on clicking LinkButton ? or we should use handler

Comment: As i mention i have <input id="lnkImg" runat="server" type="button" value="ShowImage" />  not link button

Comment: don't need any handler for this

Comment: Than its not getting called at server side if i call LinkButton1_Click

Comment: So, are you Using html Button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65606/discussion-between-king-fisher-and-user1280492).